# iOS Build not reflecting in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

I uploaded iOS build from XCode 8.1 (macOS Sierra), it uploaded successfully but not reflected on iTunes connect
Then I tried same build uploading from Application Loader, it shown me error

> "Redundant Binary Upload" error.

So I increased build number and tried uploading it from Application Loader, now it uploaded successfully again but not reflected on store.

Does anyone came across this issue ? Please let me know if I am missing something.

**Note:** I added all permissions and entitlements.

Comment: You need to wait for a few minutes to see your app on iTunes Connect (about 10~15 minutes in my opinion).

Comment: I uploaded it last night, still its not displaying.

Comment: do like add another another build number and upload again

Comment: I missed Value in plist for key "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription". I added that and build gets uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it will take some time for the binary to be processed before you can select it in itunes connect.

Check your email, and wait for an email with this title

> iTunes Connect: Version 8.8.8 (23) for My Awesome App has completed
>   processing.

Or if your binary have some problem, itunes connect will also contact you with this kind of email

> iTunes Connect: Your app "My Awesome App" (Apple ID: 888xxx888) has
>   one or more issues

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when some entries are missing in Info.plist file. 
Please ensure entries like below are included in Info.plist if your app uses them. (This is introduced in iOS 10 onwards)

- NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription
- NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
- NSCameraUsageDescription
- NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

etc.

You may get an email from iTunesConnect as well with subject - "Your app has one or more issues".